# how to use a supplied username and password to read a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, permissions

I need to read a bunch of binary files from a Java script running on Windows.

However, the folder that the files are in has limited permissions.  I (i.e. my Windows username) have permissions to read them, but the user that Java runs as (this is part of a web application) does not.  If I pass my own username and Windows network password into Java at runtime, is there a way I can read those files using my own permissions rather than the web user's?

(Note that this is NOT happening over the web; this is a one-time import script running in the context of a web application.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a network share and then connect via [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import jcifs.smb.SmbException;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SmbFileInputStream fis = null;
        try
        {
            fis = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://DOMAIN;USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/SHARE/filename.txt");
            // handle as you would a normal input stream... this example prints the contents of the file
            int length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
                {
                    System.out.print((char) buffer[x]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SmbException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fis != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ignore)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are on a network-share you could use the [net](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) tool. With

```
runtime.exec("net use ...")
```

to open and close the share. I guess that should work